# When I try to run the code provided in a paper, it has following errors related to CVXPY

Tags: python, pip, cvxpy

**When I try to run the code provided in a paper, it has the following errors related to CVXPY:**

```
(bayesrace) C:\Users\Lenovo\bayesrace>pip install -e .

Obtaining file:///C:/Users/Lenovo/bayesrace

Collecting pandas==1.0.3

Using cached pandas-1.0.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (8.7 MB)

Collecting cvxpy==1.0.15

Using cached cvxpy-1.0.15.tar.gz (915 kB)

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

command: 'D:\Anaconda\envs\bayesrace\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, 
tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hpu8en1_\cvxpy_9e73400b3c3d4e82b6ff31bd1122b730\setup.py'"'"';file='"'"'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hpu8en1_\cvxpy_9e73400b3c3d4e82b6ff31bd1122b730\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize,'"'"'open'"'"', open)(file) if os.path.exists(file) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-hpjhbaju'cwd: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hpu8en1_\cvxpy_9e73400b3c3d4e82b6ff31bd1122b730

Complete output (1 lines):

error in cvxpy setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/6f/bcab45a432befe375f056ea31a7cc9c7468d07922768cb63c3dec5733afa/cvxpy-1.0.15.tar.gz#sha256=dff246a3fa03fe5c815f290825345a6ad5ff49df5e1882f123e632a4217bbcd1 (from https://pypi.org/simple/cvxpy/). 

Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cvxpy==1.0.15 (from bayes-race) (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.2.6, 0.2.7, 0.2.9, 0.2.10, 0.2.11, 0.2.12, 0.2.13, 0.2.14, 0.2.15, 0.2.16, 0.2.17, 0.2.18, 0.2.19, 0.2.20, 0.2.21, 0.2.22, 0.2.23, 0.2.24, 0.2.25, 0.2.26, 0.2.27, 0.2.28, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 0.4.8, 0.4.9, 0.4.10, 0.4.11, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.12, 1.0.13, 1.0.14, 1.0.15, 1.0.16, 1.0.17, 1.0.18, 1.0.19, 1.0.20, 1.0.21, 1.0.22, 1.0.23, 1.0.24, 1.0.25, 1.0.26, 1.0.27, 1.0.28, 1.0.29, 1.0.31, 1.1.0a0, 1.1.0a1, 1.1.0a2, 1.1.0a3, 1.1.0a4, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.1.9, 1.1.10, 1.1.11, 1.1.12, 1.1.13, 1.1.14, 1.1.15, 1.1.16, 1.1.17, 1.1.18)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for cvxpy==1.0.15
```

**To Reproduce:**

You can find the code for this paper here: https://github.com/jainachin/bayesrace

And I am running the code in the installation section on this page.

**When I run the first 4 lines of code, it has no errors, the first 4 lines of code is:**

```
conda create --name bayesrace python=3.6

conda activate bayesrace

git clone https://github.com/jainachin/bayesrace.git

cd bayesrace/
```

**But when I try to run the 5th line of code, that is** (pip install -e .), **the above errors occurred.**

**You can also find the bugs/errors image here:**
[image]

I am using Windows 11.

Answer (score 2):

[`use_2to3` has been removed from `setuptools` 58.0 and newer](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2086).

However, newer versions (1.1+) of `cvxpy` don't use the flag.

1. Primarily, try using a newer version of `cvxpy`.
2. If that fails, downgrade your `setuptools` to a version less than 58.0.

Comment: Thank you for the instruction and I will try both steps and report back later.

Comment: Sorry, do you know how to check the version of both cvxpy and setuptools installed in this conda environment(sample codes)? And I am using the anaconda prompt. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the instruction, the problem has been solved by downgrading the setuptools to a lower version.